# How to bind bootstrap tooltip on dynamic elements

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, tooltip

When using Bootstrap tooltip, we need to write something like this to have tooltip functionality:

```
$(".showtooltip").tooltip();
```

But the problem is, we need to rerun that code every time when new content is loaded via ajax. Is there anyway to run the code for once and auto apply the tooltip when new element is loaded?

Thank you.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You need to use `selector` property.
See on the **[documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#tooltips)** :

> "If a selector is provided, tooltip objects will be delegated to the
> specified targets. In practice, this is used to enable dynamic HTML
> content to have tooltips added. See [this](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/4215) and an [informative
> example](http://jsfiddle.net/fScua/)."

JS example code :

```
$('body').tooltip({
    selector: '.createdDiv'
});

$('#add-button').click(function() {
    $('<div class="createdDiv" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Some tooltip text!">Hover over me</div>').appendTo('#container');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6NVQS/1/)**

Comment: I needed the `select: '.classname'` in order for mine to work. I'm using handlebars to dynamically load templates and populating them with ajax calls. While the tooltips are working on the items loaded on initial page load, they just were not working on the dynamic elements until I added the selector. Thank you.

Answer (score 52):

Try this:

```
$('body').tooltip({
    selector: '[data-toggle="tooltip"]'
});
```

Comment: You may need to attach this to your document ready event:   `$(document).ready(function(){
     $('body').tooltip({
    selector: '[data-toggle="tooltip"]'
   });
  });`

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap 4:

```
$(document).tooltip({selector: '[data-toggle="tooltip"]'});

$(document).popover({selector: '[data-toggle="popover"]'});
```

Answer (score 0):

**<= Bootstrap v5.x**, `tooltip()` doesn't exist in JQuery object.

So I came up with this self made solution.

**I don't really know about performance problems or any better workaround.**

So if there is a better solution to this, just let me know in the comments so I remove or update my answer.

Here is what I did and works for me :

```
var body = $('body');
body.on('mouseover', '[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    return new bootstrap.Tooltip(this).show();
});

body.on('mouseleave', '[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]', function (e) {
    $('[role="tooltip"]').fadeOut(function () {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found all presented examples as very complex. Maybe JQuery and Bootstrap have changed since then.

You can use this as the very simple one:

```
  $('#myButtonId').prop('title', 'Trustee election in effect');
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's what got mine working:

I have this function, officially from [bootstrap docs.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/tooltips/#example-enable-tooltips-everywhere)

```
function initializeBootstrapTooltip()
{
  var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'))
  var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
    return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl)
  })
}
```

I then call this function when the DOM has finished loading during page load as well as after I load the dynamic content the DOM like so:

```
function addDynamicContent()
{
  $('#element').html('<span data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top">Tooltip on top</span >');
  initializeBootstrapTooltip();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**In Bootstrap 5;**

```
// to enable tooltips, with default configuration
$('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()

// to initialize tooltips with given configuration
$('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({ boundary: 'clippingParents', customClass: 'myClass' })
```

If you don't want to use jQuery, [see the BS5 docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/javascript/#sanitizer) on using pure Js

Answer (score -1):

I've created an example for Bootstrap 5.
You have a button with a tooltip which shows on click.
Then you have a button to duplicate the previous button.

The on click event is added to the newly created button, and when you click it, the tooltip will also appear. The first time is triggered manually.

Here's the code:

```js
var elms = $('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]');
elms.each(function(){
  new bootstrap.Tooltip($(this));
});

$("#target").on( "click", 'a[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]' , function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  
  if ( ! bootstrap.Tooltip.getInstance( $(this) ))
  new bootstrap.Tooltip( $(this) ).show();
});


$("#duplicate-btn").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#target").append( $(".tooltip-btn").clone()[0] );
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@latest/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@latest/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">

  <p class="m-5">
    <a class="btn btn-primary tooltip-btn" href="#" data-bs-trigger="focus" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-html="true" data-bs-title="somethink cool">Click Me for Tooltip</a>
  </p>

  <p class="m-5">
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" id="duplicate-btn">Let's Duplicate</a>
  </p>

  <p class="m-5" id="target">
  </p>

</div>
```