# Yii2 - How to add JQuery tooltip to GridView with pagination

Tags: jquery, gridview, yii2

How do I add a tooltip to column data in a GridView?   It works on the first page, but after changing to a different page, the tooltip doesn't work.

*Main Layout File:*

```
\yii\web\JqueryAsset::register($this);
\yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset::register($this);
$js = <<< 'SCRIPT'
/* To initialize BS3 tooltips set this below */
$(function () { 
    $("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip(); 
});;
/* To initialize BS3 popovers set this below */
$(function () { 
    $("[data-toggle='popover']").popover(); 
});
SCRIPT;
// Register tooltip/popover initialization javascript
$this->registerJs($js);
```

*Code from View:*

```
[   'class' => '\kartik\grid\DataColumn',
    'attribute'=>'default_rate_id',
    'value'=>function($data) {
        if(isset($data->rate->code)) {
            return Html::tag('div', $data->rate->code, ['data-toggle'=>'tooltip','data-placement'=>'left','title'=>$data->rate->name,'style'=>'cursor:default;']);
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    },
    'width' => '60px',
    'filterType'=>GridView::FILTER_SELECT2,
    'filterWidgetOptions'=>[
        'pluginOptions' =>['allowClear' =>true],
        'data' => $this->listRateCodes(),
    ],
    'filterInputOptions' =>['placeholder' =>' '],
    'format'=>'raw',
],
```

**Solution:**

Thanks to @arogachev, I have updated the appropriate section in the Main Layout File to be as follows.  The tooltips now show on every page of the GridView.

```
$js = <<< 'SCRIPT'
/* To initialize BS3 tooltips set this below */
    $('body').tooltip({selector: '[data-toggle="tooltip"]'});
/* To initialize BS3 popovers set this below */
    $('body').popover({selector: '[data-toggle="popover"]'});
SCRIPT;
// Register tooltip/popover initialization javascript
$this->registerJs($js);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because in this case content of `GridView` is dynamic and changed with each `AJAX` request. On first page load it works because nothing has changed yet, but once content gets changed it doesn't.

Solution is to change the way of specifying tooltips with `jQuery`:

```
$('body').tooltip({
    selector: '[data-toggle="tooltip"]'
});
```

See these related questions:

- [How do I bind Twitter Bootstrap tooltips to dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958825/how-do-i-bind-twitter-bootstrap-tooltips-to-dynamically-created-elements)
- [How to bind bootstrap tooltip on dynamic elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24655291/how-to-bind-bootstrap-tooltip-on-dynamic-elements)