# Bootstrap tooltip does't work when I use jQuery to append the tooltip elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

how are you guys I have a question if anyone can help me, I'll be grateful.

at the moment I was using some bootstrap functionality, for example, this code below.
     I'm using bootstrap version 3

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12  div_challenger" style="background-color: #somecolor; color:someTextColor;"
    data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="some text here!!!">
    <span class="some icon"></span>
    <b>some title</b>
    <input type="hidden" value="somevalue" name="inputChallengerSelected">
</div>
```

this code works well in html file. 
But when I use Jquery append element this doesn't work the same way

code using jquery append.

```
<button id="someid" onclick="addElement()"> ADD element </button>
<div id="addhere"> </div>
```

script tags

```
<script>
function addElement(){
   let ElementToAdd = `    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12  div_challenger" style="background-color: #somecolor; color:someTextColor;"
    data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="some text here!!!">
    <span class="some icon"></span>
    <b>some title</b>
    <input type="hidden" value="somevalue" name="inputChallengerSelected">
</div>`
 $('#addhere').append(ElementToAdd)
}
```

**if someone tells me why this occurs I will be totally grateful**

Comment: Is it the tooltip that isn't working after you append that markup?

Comment: It's probably because bootstrap is using a page load event to attach its listeners. When you dynamically append items, it doesn't attach listeners to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this: 
[How to bind bootstrap tooltip on dynamic elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24655291/how-to-bind-bootstrap-tooltip-on-dynamic-elements/24655395)

In order to make a dynamically injected tooltip work, you must initialize a tooltip plugin using an element, which exists already after the page is loaded, e.g. body. It should then work.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it really helped me a lot.

Comment: Just add this in my function  $('body').tooltip({
            selector: '[data-toggle="tooltip"]'
        });

Comment: just more one thing kkk, in this moment I need to use my external functions, how I can implements this, in my dynamics elements ?

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer is Bootstrap = CSS + JS.
Try to hide element onload and when you need show.

Comment: this works, but in this case I need a dynamic way, but thanks for your help <3